ROS 2 Jazzy: Unable to Install Webots distributed package
I'm currently trying to install the distributed package for ros2_webots but keep receiving a package not found error.
This is what the error looks like:
➜  ~ sudo apt install ros-jazzy-webots-ros2 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jazzy-webots-ros2

and when I look at the list of possible packages to install, all I see are:
➜  ~ sudo apt install ros-jazzy-webots-ros2 
ros-jazzy-webots-ros2-importer     ros-jazzy-webots-ros2-msgs-dbgsym
ros-jazzy-webots-ros2-msgs         ros-jazzy-webots-ros2-tests      

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it seems that I'm able to install every other ros2 jazzy package except webots!

To better interpret your question, could you please specify your operating system and whether you installed ros2 as binary or source? My system is ubuntu 22.04 and I am using ros2 humble and the command sudo apt install ros-humble-webots-ros2 works without any problems.
If installation problems persist, I recommend you try  https://gazebosim.org/docs/latest/ros_installation/.  Gazebo Harmonic simulation program works with ros2 jazzy

I had the same problem. Instead of installing it like you did, I installed the webots from the source, as shown in this page https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Installation-Ubuntu.html
